# Redirecting all links from page1 to page2 when coming from external links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

How can I redirect all **external** links (ie clicks from Google towards my site) from product.php?id=1&cat=2&show=3 to new_product.php?id=1&cat=2&show=3 ?

The reason is, product.php is used only in a colorbox window without header/footer/menus etc for users that already on the website. If someone is linking directly to this page from, let's say Google results, they're getting an incomplete layout, whereas new_product.php has the full layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited:

Did you try something like this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com/.*$ [NC]
```

and now the rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^product.php? http://yourdomain.com/new_product.php? [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Will this work only when requests for product.php are made from outside the domain yoururl.com? Or will it also redirect while someone is browsing the site?

Comment: this only fires if HTTP_REFERER is not www.yoururl.com. 
maybe you should take www and without www.

Comment: I suppose it will work then, i'll let you know tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: tested it. there is a problem when no referer is defined (e.g. link from email. or when actually being on the website - there is no referer). so it's probably not working. why don't solve it with php? e.g. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']